# Does threads of ThreadPoolExecutor not runs concurrently using with PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I am using java ThreadPoolExecutor to run concurrent thread execution. I used ArrayBlockingQueue to keep threads in queue. But now requirement has changed and I need to add thread run time(no size limit) and it should be prioritized. 
So i decided to use PriorityBlockingQueue instead of ArrayBlockingQueue with some comparison Logic.
After using PriorityBlockingQueue, threads are running sequentially one after one not concurrently. Only one thread run at a time, rather than whatever the active thread count will be.
Please let me know if anybody have any suggestions to resolve this issue and achieve my requirement(thread should be added in pool at run time and it execution should be based on priority).

My demo code:

```
//RejectedExecutionHandler implementation
    RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl rejectionHandler = new RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl();
    //Get the ThreadFactory implementation to use
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(50, ThreadComparator.getComparator());
    ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, activeThread, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue, threadFactory, rejectionHandler);
    //start the monitoring thread
    MyMonitorThread monitor = new MyMonitorThread(executorPool, 20, "Demo");
    Thread monitorThread = new Thread(monitor);
    monitorThread.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < totalThead; i++) {
        int prio = i % 3 == 0 ? 3 : 5;
        executorPool.execute(new MyThread("Thread-" + i, prio));        
    }

    // Inserting more threads in between concurrent execution.
    try {
        Thread.sleep(40000);
        for (int j = 101; j < 110; j++) {
            executorPool.execute(new MyThread("Thread-" + j, 2));
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    while(executorPool.getActiveCount() != 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while thread sleeping: " + e);
        }
    }
    //shut down the pool
    executorPool.shutdown();
    //shut down the monitor thread
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while thread sleeping: " + e);
    }
    monitor.shutdown();
```

---

```
 public abstract class ThreadComparator implements Comparator<Runnable>{

public static Comparator<Runnable> getComparator() {
    return new Comparator<Runnable>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Runnable t1, Runnable t2) {
            CompareToBuilder compare = new CompareToBuilder();
            MyThread mt1 = (MyThread) t1;
            MyThread mt2 = (MyThread) t2;
            compare.append(mt1.getPriority(), mt2.getPriority());
            return compare.toComparison();
        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: It's really hard to answer a question like this in the abstract. Changing from an ArrayBlockingQueue to a PriorityBlockingQueue should not impact your application's concurrency. If you share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the behavior you're seeing it would be easier to help.

Comment: I hope above mentioned code will make it easier to understand the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of `ThreadPoolExecutor` with an unbounded work queue.

To cite the [`ThreadPoolExecutor` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> **Core and maximum pool sizes**
>   A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size [..].
>   When a new task is submitted in method execute(Runnable), and **fewer
>   than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created** to
>   handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there
>   are **more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads
>   running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full**. [...]

Since you define `corePoolSize` as `1` and a `PriorityBlockingQueue` is essentially an unbounded queue (that can never become full), you will never have more than one thread.

The fix is to adjust the `corePoolSize` to the required number of threads.

Comment: Can I set corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize equal?

Comment: @PrakashKumar sure, the only requirement is that corePoolSize may not be greater maximumPoolSize. From the documentation: "By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a fixed-size thread pool."

Comment: I need to ask one question, if I add more threads in queue while execution. ThreadPool is picking threads randomly from queue with same priority. Can i make sequential with equal priority. Means pool picks threads sequential for equal priority

Comment: @PrakashKumar the JavaDoc for PriorityBlockingQueue (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) has an example class (`FIFOEntry`) that you could adopt to your need (executing tasks with equal priority in insertion order). Basically it boils down to adding a "timestamp" field to the tasks that gets assigned incrementing numbers on insertion.

Comment: Thanks for yours suggestions, I have achieved everything i wanted. Now i need some more changes for my R&D, Looking for solution/demo/code to run several jobs separately/independently. 
My requirement is as below: 
All jobs have a threadpool, I can manage active running thread(increase or decrease run time), to full utilization of CPU cores. 

Is it possible or not and anyone have suggestion/solution?